# How to implement malloc operation in C#

Tags: c#, memory-management

```
float **ThreadID;
int Nthreads;
```

How to perform below task in C#?

```
ThreadID = (float **)malloc( Nthreads* sizeof(float *) );
```

Comment: You do not allocate memory manually in C#.

Comment: Why would you ever need to do that? The .NET runtime is a managed runtime - you don't need to manage your own memory.

Comment: What if someone wants to have a deeper control on memory allocation. There is a big advantage in storage if you can have continuous allocated memory, which you will understand when you work on data structures.

Comment: What if someone wants to have a deeper control on memory allocation. There is a big advantage in storage if you can have continuous allocated memory, which you will understand when you work on data structures.

Answer (score 6):

You can try using the following:

```
Marshal.AllocHGlobal
```

Details are on [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.allochglobal.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

Is there any reason why you need unmanaged memory for your application?
Otherwise the normal way to do it would be

```
ThreadID = new float*[Nthreads];
```

That will allocate a new Array for you. If you use this kind of statement in a function that is called a lot, you might want to add the stackalloc-keyword. otherwise slow garbage collection could leed to increased memory consumption. With stackalloc it will be stored on the stack and destroyed as any other local variable upon leaving the function.

```
ThreadID = stackalloc float*[Nthreads];
```

EDIT: As with all pointers in C#, you need to declare the unsafe context for your function, like

```
unsafe int doSomething(){
   ...
}
```

Comment: @RitchMelton: +1 for pionting out my mistake

Comment: While using ThreadID = new float*[Nthreads]; it gives error saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'float*[]' to 'float**'"

Answer (score 3):

```
float[][] ThreadId;
int NThreads;

ThreadId = new float[Nthreads][];
```